# What am I doing wrong with this php and pdo connection string?

Tags: php, pdo

I have two files index.php and header.php

This is header.php

```
<?php
$host ="localhost";
$user ="hosting_user";
$db = "hosting_dbname";
$pass ="lamepassword";

$odb = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $host . ";dbname= . $db, $user, $pass);
?>
```

this is index.php

```
<?php require_once("header.php");?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Web Dev 1</title>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post" action">
    Name: <input type="text" id="Box_num" name="Box_num" /><br />
    Age: <input type="text" id="Names" name="Names" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="add" />
    </form>
    <?php
        $query = "SELECT * FROM Owners";
        $result =$odb->query($query);
        if($result->)rowCount() > 0) {
            foreach($result as $item){
                echo($item['Box_num'] .<br />/n");
        }
    }
    </body>
</html>
```

When I load index.php, all I get is a blank screen. When I use mysqli it works but doesnt load the sql query

Comment: You're missing a `"` at the end of your PDO string?

Comment: Thanks!!!! Ugg I can't believe I didnt see that.

Comment: Missing an open quote before `<br />/n"` as well

Comment: `($result->)rowCount() > 0)` a rogue closing parentheses. - `echo($item['Box_num'] .<br />/n");` a missing opening quote mark

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a few PHP syntax errors here.

It should read:

```
$odb = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $host . ";dbname=" . $db, $user, $pass);
```

There also seems to be errors in your syntax in `index.php`.  My suggestion would be to [enable error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/845025/1356593) so you can detect these errors yourself.  You can also try using PHP's lint tool via the command line `php` executable.  That will also detect *fatal* parser errors.

Ex:

```
php -l /path/to/index.php
```